Token doesn't match specifier '%d'" Error When Parsing Logs - How to Correctly Set the Log Format?
I'm using GoAccess to parse NGINX access logs, but I'm encountering an error when trying to match the date and time format. I haven't been able to correctly set the log format for GoAccess to parse my log lines correctly.
GoAccess Version:

GoAccess - version 1.7 - Jan  4 2023 18:36:47

Example Log Line:
10.211.98.48 [10.211.98.48] - - [20/Aug/2024:00:18:04 +0000] - artifactory.my.dev - ~(?<repo>.+)\x5C.binary "GET /artifactory/api/docker/quay/v2/token?scope=repository%3Aargoproj%2Fworkflow-controller%3Apull&service=artifactory.my.dev HTTP/1.1" [/artifactory/api/docker/quay/v2/token] 200 144 "-" "containerd/v1.7.1" [0.009 0.009]

Command I’m Using:
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" goaccess access.log -o report.html --log-format='%h %^[%d/%b/%Y:%T %z]' --date-format=%d/%b/%Y --time-format=%T --debug-file=debug.log 

Error:
[PARSING access.log] {0} @ {0/s}
Cleaning up resources...
==1819== FILE: access.log
==1819== Parsed 1 lines producing the following errors:
==1819== Token '10.211.98.48] - - [20' doesn't match specifier '%d'
==1819== Format Errors - Verify your log/date/time format

What I've tried:

Adjusted specifiers like %^ and [%^] to properly ignore characters before the date.
Used cat -A to check for hidden characters in the log file.
Tried different combinations of the log format, but GoAccess keeps returning the date parsing error.

How can I correctly set the --log-format for GoAccess to properly parse the given log line? Are there any specific guidelines or tips for using specifiers to ignore characters before the date and time?
Additional Information:

The log files have dates formatted as [20/Aug/2024:00:18:04 +0000].
I'm using LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" to ensure dates are processed in English.

